# How can I hide an element with CSS for a certain length of time?

Tags: css, css-animations

I need to hide a button for 10 minutes. Can I do this with CSS?

I do know CSS a bit, but not quite that well. I think I can start this code, but after this I don't know what to do:

```
#button {
        animation:delay;
}
```

Comment: You need JS for that. If you really care about security, you will also need to have checks server-side as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript Approach**

Are you opposed to handling this through Javascript?

It would be fairly trivial to do using the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function assuming it was already hidden:

```
<!-- Your initially hidden button -->
<button id='button' style='display: none;'>Click me!</button>
<!-- Your script to display your button after 10 minutes -->
<script>
   // setTimeout will trigger a function after a specified delay (in milliseconds)
   setTimeout(function(){ 
        // When your timeout has finished, find your button and show it
        document.getElementById('button').style.display = 'block';
   }, 10 * 6000);
</script>
```

You can [see a working example of this here](http://jsbin.com/hawari/1/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below using a 5-second delay :

[image]

**Pure CSS Approach**

You may be able to accomplish this by creating a [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) along with the appropriate delay similar to the concept demonstrated in your initial post :

```
#button {
     /* Initial value (hidden through opacity) */
     opacity: 0;
     /* Various cross-browser declarations for your animation */
     -webkit-animation: delayedShow 0.1s forwards;
     -moz-animation: delayedShow 0.1s forwards;
     -ms-animation: delayedShow 0.1s forwards;
     -o-animation: delayedShow 0.1s forwards;
     animation: delayedShow 0.1s forwards;
     /* Your delay (in this case 600 seconds) */
     animation-delay: 600s;
}
/* Your animation declaration (transitions from opacity of 0 to 1) */
@keyframes delayedShow {
     from { opacity: 0; }
     to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

This uses the [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) property to hide and transition your element from hidden `0` to shown `1` after a delay of 10 minutes (600 seconds). Additionally, the [`forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) property will ensure that the end value of your transition persists after the animation has completed.

You can [see an example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/kapobuz/2/edit?html,css,output) and demonstrated below as well :

[image]

**Worth Noting**

Since both of these approaches are purely client-side code, they require that the page not be refreshed or posted back during that time as it will reset your timer. If this doesn't work for your needs, you would likely need to use some server-side approach to determine when the "timer" was done and then show your button that way.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add a delay time?

```
animation-delay: 10s;
```